# C++ Boost Variant Error

Tags: c++, boost

I have been playing around with boost variant and came across a scenario that seems problematic, but that I feel is my lack of knowledge on how properly use boost variant. Here is a little tester program I put together

```
main.cpp

#include <boost/variant.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdint.h>

typedef boost::variant<uint16_t, uint32_t> MyInt;

int main()
{
    uint16_t regular = 11;
    MyInt custom = regular;

    std::cout << custom << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Ok so the above works fine, but I get an error if I try to do the following:

```
int16_t invalid = 11;
MyInt custom = invalid; // This line causes the error.
```

I expected to get an error, but the error doesn't tell me where my problem actually occurred in my main, but in Boost's classes which isn't the most helpful when working in a bigger project.

I started to look into boost visitors to place the error in main, but didn't quite see how those would solve my issue here. Am I on the right track with visitors or am I missing some else?

Edit:

The real question here is invalid assignment of any type not specified in my variant (i.e. char, std::string, double, etc.) not so much converting int16_t to a uint16_t.

Comment: where exactly are you adding those two lines? (BTW you have a type-o in the name of myInt)

Comment: How about using another compiler? Clang 3.7 delivers some very useful error message for this code. It also pinpoints the source of the error to the line `MyInt custom = invalid; // This line causes the error.`

Comment: No typo in MyInt, It's a typedef and I'm replacing the first 2 lines in main with them @ RichardHodges

Comment: @rettichschnidi you think it is a compiler specific thing? I was using Visual Studio compiler, but it didn't point t my main function for the error. I might give that a try when I can today.

Comment: If your question is about readable error messages, there's nothing you can do. Just assign correct values. The fact that assignment fails should make it pretty obvious that the value is not unambiguously convertible.

Comment: @sehe What I'm asking is if I am using boost variant properly for assignment. I read the documentation and looked over a few tuts. I would like to think that when I try to assign an invalid value to a variant, I would get a nice error pointing me to exactly where I made the mistake just like if I tried assigning a double to an int. Sadly the variant doesn't seem to work as nice. I know these kind of error messages show up in other areas of C++, but they are not intuitive and just cause confusion in larger projects so I like to avoid them if I can.

Comment: And that's not the case. You're using assignment correctly.

Answer (score 0):

`int16_t` requires an implicit conversion for both `uint16_t` and `uint32_t`. Therefore, there is no best overload and the assignment/initialization fails to compile.

Coerce your type:

```
my_int = static_cast<int32_t>(int16_t_value);
```

Comment: I'll clarify the question, but I don't particularly care about converting int16_t to uint16_t. I was getting at the point of assigning a type not in the variant (i.e. anything not uintXX_t)

Comment: You weren't getting at that point. Even with the "clarified" question. What is the question about assigning bogus values into a variant? Why would you expect it to compile? What should it do? Are you looking for `boost::any`? (If so - that's a design smell 99% of the time, so: why?)